# Choose appropriate contour for a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I have a problem to solve integral
$$
I = \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x-z)(1+x^2)^{\kappa+2}}
$$

I can solve the same integral with borders $-\infty$ to $\infty$ using residue theorem but here I have a problem to define contour (if complex analysis if right way to do).

Could someone please help me?

Comment: What are $z$ and $\kappa$?

Comment: I think nobody will try to solve your problem unless you say something about $\large z$ and $\large\kappa$.